# Socket.io offline messages

Tags: ios, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am trying to create a mobile chat application using socket.io. I am planning to store the messages on a local database on the users phone so I don't have to perform http requests to my database to retrieve old messages. My chat application consists of rooms of up to 12 people.

In socket.io I subscribe to a room like this: `socket.join(room` and broadcast messages through that. All users in my room and connected to the socket receive the message and it all works fine, however I wanted to implement offline messaging so if someone wasn't connected it would save the text to the database. My problem is how do I know which users werent online to receive the message, do I pass the users in the room when I am joining a specific room? Because currently I don't know how to save messages in my database because socket doesnt know about the people who are in the room but not connected.

Comment: You are going to have to NOT rely on socket.io to keep track of rooms because when a user goes offline, it removes the user from the room.  Instead, a room will have to be something you keep in your database and when a user comes online, you look them up in the database and join them to any socket.io rooms that they should be in.  Likewise, when you send a message to a room, you have to look up the room in the database and add the message to a msg queue for that user in the database if they are not currently online.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to save the messages into a database and fetching it when user connects to the room (I have a chat application where we do this. We save messages to mongodb with room references and retrieve it based on room ID). 
Socket io does not hold any messages so every time a user connects to a room u should query to the database and get all new messages. Since u have a database of all the messages in your mobile use the date of the messages to get all the new messages.

Or

you can hold the user's vs room reference when user is disconnecting you just have a reference saying this user who is connected to this room is going offline, with some time stamp. When the user returns use the time stamp to retrieve messages from some other client and sent him those messages

Comment: The problem is I can't save my message by room id because I only want to retrieve it once so I save a separate row in my database for every message so when a user retrieves a message it is deleted from the database and added to my local database on the users phone

Comment: What I was thinking was when a user connects to the room he provides an array of everyone that is in the room/group chat (online and offline) and when a message is sent it removes the people who received the message from the array and saves a record in the database for the rest of the users in the array which will only have the users who aren't online

Comment: Wouldn't that complicate stuff. As you say the message is deleted after retrieval then some one in the room has a copy just use that copy to distribute to all the people who are offline
I don't know about your business scenario but I am just saying what will happen to all the messages user received if user uninstalls and reinstalls your application for some and his local database is cleared

Comment: How can I distribute it among users, how do I know who received and who still needs to receive a message. And for the local database being cleared, it is normal most chat applications on the app store work that way so if you get a new phone or reinstall you start from scratch just like the native iMessage app for iPhone for example

Comment: Do u have a record of all the rooms user is connected to if u do then u can solve it like this, when user is disconnecting (use the even in socket.io on disconnect )  save a reference saying this user is going offline with a timestamp when the user returns use the timestamp to check with other users in same room if new messages where sent if so update connecting user with new messages

Comment: Hi, i have a quick question regarding a similar topic, when a message is sent i save it to my postgres db but if the user is offline then go goes back online, my get requests get all the messages for that user but doesnt show that the message is a new message (Bold text), how can i achieve this?